# How to use token-based authentication with axios and react

Tags: reactjs, axios

There is 401 error(Invalid or not provided access token), How to pass token correctly with axios, This is my code &
API documentation: https://trefle.io

[image]

Comment: you are trying to do **client-side** auth, have you read the docs for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [trefle docs](https://trefle.io/reference#section/Authentication/Client-side-apps), you first need to request a client-side token which will return JWT token, that'll be used to make requests from client side.

```
// requst JWT token 
https://trefle.io/api/auth/claim?token=YOUR-TOKEN&origin=YOUR-WEBSITE-URL
```

The plant endpoint accepts two params, `id` path parameter and `token` query parameter.

[image: pant endpoint]
You need to pass your token as a query parameter.

```
componentDidMount = () => {

    axios.get('https://trefle.io/api/plants/103505?token=YOURTOKEN')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

or

```
componentDidMount = () => {

    axios.get('https://trefle.io/api/plants/103505', {
      params: {
        token: 'YOURTOKEN'
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on how your API is setup to consume the token. Generally speaking though you can pass in a token through the headers property in axios.

```
axios.get("https://trefle.io//api/plants/${id}", {
   headers: {
      Authorization : yourtoken
   } 
})
```

Comment: @Ravisara awesome. Did that make your feature work?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you have organized your code/architecture.

- You can store the token in session or local storages, but each time you make a call you need to pass the token through the headers each time OR you can create an interceptor which will handle that for you.
- You can store the token in the cookie as well. This is good if you are running you React app with node using server-side rendering (SSR). In this case you don't need to do something, as cookie are being send through headers automatically.
- You can also store the token in a session, but in case you care about auto-scaling, you need to use Redis and not a memory storage, so token will be available for all the instances your app is running on.

Small note - don't send the token through query params.

Comment: If it is the API, then there is no other option, my answer is in general.

Comment: and the question   specifically says, he gets 401. I don't know how session storage and cookies have to do with that.

Comment: ok, this's just an opinion, as it doesn't answer the question?